# Summation of this infinite series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I was just reading how Euler came about the result of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ = $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

(From [here](http://ptrow.com/articles/Infinite_Series_Sept_07.htm) )

So instead if I had the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-n)^2}$ ; $x>1$

how do I go about solving it?

Comment: Then you would divide by zero.

Comment: That wont converge ..

Comment: See the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) at $\;\zeta(2,1-x)$ for analytic continuation in $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If $x \in (1,\infty)\setminus \mathbb{N}$ then the sum converges since $(x-n)^2 \sim n^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Since the original question had $x$ and $n$ exchanged I assumed $n$ (now $x$) to be an integer. I'm changing the vars names to conform to the question, but my answer only applies to the case in which $x$ is an integer.

First of all you should avoid $n=x$ in the summation, otherwise you divide by $0$.

Then, you can see that for $n=x+1$, $n=x+2$, $n=x+3$, etc. you have exactly the Euler sum, because $(x-(x+1)=-1$, $(x-(x+2)=-2$, etc. and when you take the squares the minus sign goes away so you have exactly the same series.

Then you must add the terms with $n<x$. This sum has not a closed form.

So in practice the sum will be something like
$$
  \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{k^2}\,,
$$
where $x$ is your parameter.
This answer only applies to the case in which $x$ is an integer.

Comment: So we are assuming $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes Giovanni Resta, and Gerry Myerson x is an integer.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ajpk If you are treating the sum as a function of $x$, then it is equivalent to a polygamma function $\psi ^{(1)}(1-x)$, which is not elementary

Comment: so now the part $\sum_{k=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{k^2}$ would be equivalent to $\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \psi^{(1)} (n)$ where $\psi^{(n)} (x)$ is the nth derivative of the digamma function?

Comment: @ajpk No, the author of the post takes integer value of $x$, and didn't count the term when $n=x$. For example, if $x=3$ , the term $\frac 1{3-3}$ would diverge. By the way, it should be the first derivative of the digamma function with input $1-x$ (that is $\psi ' (1-x)$), but not the $x^{th}$ derivative. And for any positive integer value $x$, the function tends to infinity, corresponding to the fact that the sum diverges

Comment: @Giovanni Resta in reference to this question, what If I have
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)^2+c^2}
$$
where c in a complex number?

Comment: @aswa09 I have no idea, you better ask as a separate question.